# vim as editor for mutt: specify to open newline under header as command line option

Tags: vim, mutt

I use vim as editor for mail in mutt (edit_headers enabled) and I pass options to it using the `editor`variable in `muttrc`:

```
set editor="nvim  \"+set tw=80\"  \"+set fo=aw\" \"+set nonumber\" \"+set spell\" +/^$/ \"+nohl\" +o"
```

This gets the cursor into the line separating header from body, but the actual body text would of course start in a new line underneath. So I press "o" to open a newline and can start typing.

Is there a way to tell vim to do the "press o" automatically so that I can start typing right away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[+startinsert](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#:startinsert) or [+"normal o"](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#o)

`startinsert` starts Insert mode **in the current line**, not the next line. `normal o` simulates pressing `o` in Normal mode.

Comment: This indeed works, but I have to specify both (`\"+ normal o\" \"+startinsert\"`) to end up in insert mode.

Comment: For some reason I need to put `+/^$/` between`\"`. So my complete command looks like this: `set editor="nvim  \"+/^$/\" \"+nohl\" \"+ normal o\" \"+startinsert\"`

Comment: This is because `set editor=""` has external quotes so internal quotes must be escaped. You can use apostrophes: `set editor="nvim '+/^$/' '+nohl' '+normal o' '+startinsert'"`